# devtoolset-7 stl_vector.h undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'

Tags: linux, undefined, centos7, stdvector, libstdc++

I am currently trying compile my program on CentOS 7, and below error has occurred.

It works well with ubuntu 18.04, but it is not works with CentOS 7.

```
db/obj-db.o: In function `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_range_check(unsigned long) const':
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:825: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'
db/obj-db.o: In function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_range_check(unsigned long) const':
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:825: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'
../bin/x64/libUFMatcher.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
../bin/x64/libUFMatcher.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:56: ../bin/x64/MatchingServer] Error 1
```

Comment: I believe you need to use the newer `libstdc++` provided by `devtoolset-7`.

Answer (score 1):

The centos 7 has a old `gcc` version, maybe `4.8.5`. But now many libraries need a more high version. You can run below commands to use a higher `gcc` version

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-8 # gcc 8 is part of this toolset
scl enable devtoolset-8 bash # make the gcc version be 8.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the linked target(object/lib) is compiled with the same version of gcc.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same compiling issue after I had a second version of `gcc/g++` on my machine (CentOS 7). The original one was installed by yum (v4.8.5) and the other was installed from source code (v4.9.2). It looks like the manual install changes `$PATH` entries order in my shell, that `/usr/local/bin` went before the `/usr/bin`. So when my code compiles, it just looks for `gcc/g++` which comes first from the `$PATH`. Since my manual installation of 4.9.2 gcc is not fully completed, there are missing libraries and its binary is under the `/usr/local/bin`.

Quick fix: just check your $PATH to see if it's messed up. For me, put `/usr/local/bin` after `/usr/bin` works.

```
# echo $PATH                                                  
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:...
```